# ¿Cómo puedo corregir mi lógica en el siguiente bucle DO-While que estoy probando?

Tags: php, condiciones, bucles, while

tengo un problema con el siguiente código, pueden ignorar lo que dice en los echo pues este no es el objetivo de lo que intento comprender y resolver. Les explico un poco, cuando ingreso valores de 1 a 24 el código entra en las condiciones respectivas una sola vez (Esto lo hace bien) y sale del ciclo, el problema está al momento de ingresar un número entre (20..30); este me debe pedir que ingrese nuevamente un valor menor que 25, si el número ingresado es menor que 25 debe evaluar nuevamente las condiciones respectivas "Menor de edad" o "Beneficiario" y salir del ciclo, de lo contrario si ingresa nuevamente un valor de (20..30 ó mayor) debería salir del ciclo echo("Nos vemos en la próxima")

```
    do {
    echo "Ingresa tu edad: ";
    $edad = fgets(STDIN);
    $repetir = 1;
    $cont = 1;
    if ($repetir <= 1) {

        if ($edad <= 18) {
            echo ("<br />" . "menor de edad: Tienes " . $edad);
            $repetir = $repetir + 1;
            $cont += 2;
        } elseif ($edad > 18 && $edad < 25) {
            echo ("<br />" . "Beneficiario: Tienes " . $edad . "<br />");
            $repetir = $repetir + 1;
            $cont += 2;
        } elseif ($edad >= 25 && $edad < 30) {

            if ($cont == 1) {
                echo ("<br />" . "Ingresa una edad menor que 25: Tienes " . $edad);
                $cont += 1;
            } else if ($cont == 2) {
                echo ("<br />" . "Nos vemos en una proxima ocasion ");
                $repetir = $repetir + 1;
                $cont += 2;
            } else {
                echo ("<br />" . ".... ");
                $cont += 1;
            }
        } else {
            echo ("<br />" . "nos vemos en un proximo intento: ");
        }
    } else {
        echo ("<br />" . ".... ");
    }
} while ($repetir <= 1 && $cont <= 2);
echo ("<br />" . " Sale del WHILE " . "<br />");
```

En esta parte intento aumentar la variable $cont en +1 para que la próxima vez que ingrese a la condición de valores entre (25..30) se vaya a la condición ($cont == 2), Pero, la variable $cont siempre tiene valor=1, por lo tanto, me va a pedir siempre que ingrese una edad menor que 25 así hasta que ingreso un número menor que 25, pero necesito que salga al segundo intento. Es decir, $cont debe ser 2 para terminar.

```
            if ($cont == 1) {
                echo ("<br />" . "Ingresa una edad menor que 25: Tienes " . $edad);
                $cont += 1;
            }
```

Condicion en la que espero que salga del ciclo

```
            else if ($cont == 2) {
                echo ("<br />" . "Nos vemos en una proxima ocasion ");
                $repetir = $repetir + 1;
                $cont += 2;
            }
```

He intentado colocar las condiciones de edad dentro de un for($i = 1; $i < 3; $i++) {}, manipulando la variable $i sin embargo el resultado es el mismo, no sale del ciclo cuando se supone que he aumento la bandera $cont o el iterador $i.

Este es un pequeño ejemplo que creé para adaptarlo a un flujo que tiene un comportamiento similar.

Por favor me pueden indicar ¿En qué parte estoy errando?, me pueden colaborar con documentación y con sus valiosísimas respuestas les agradezco mucho.

Comment: Corrijo la redacción del primer parrafo son valores  numericos de (25..30 ó mayor) no de (20...30)

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.